# while interact with touch screen i get touch id range from 2 to 11, is that differ or static?

Tags: wpf

while interacting with a touch screen I get the touch id range from 2 to 11, is that differs or static.

```
public void TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    int i = e.TouchDevice.Id;
    Debug.WriteLine(i, "{0}");
}
```

Comment: Work to specify at least what technologies are you asking abiut here, please

Comment: is this WPF technology.